# How to extract date from a long string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I a long string like below in my column and I need to extract only the date (`2021-07-05`) from it.

Could anyone please help?

```
Name - Koteswararao vp Department - Prod Location - Hyderabad Domain - ND Job Title - Technical-ABAP Date of Hire - 2021-07-05 Vendor ID - v2345 Candidate ID - Associate ID - 3334 Name - Hardware Allocation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `PATINDEX` with `SUBSTRING` here:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    SUBSTRING(col,
              PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', col),
              10) AS date
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The call to `PATINDEX` above finds the starting position of the date, while `SUBSTRING` takes 10 characters from that position.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen , I just tried this and I am not getting the ouput.

Comment: @vissubabu Then your actual data isn't what you showed us, because my query definitely works for the sample data you did reveal.

Comment: Yup - code works just fine with the sample data provided.